# Facebook like Notification Icon for Ext3 Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, extjs, ext.net

I am using an Ext toolbar which has one button called "NotificationButton" on which I plan to display numbers just like in the facebook notification. I can successfully change the html of the button. The only thing I am stuck is on the css part.

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

**Edited!**

As suggested by Daulet, at this point, I have:

**Stylesheet**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fbNotification
    {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 orange!important;
        border: 1px solid orange !important;
        border-radius: 10px !important;
        width: 18px !important;
    }

    .fbNotification .x-tip-body
    {
        font-size: 10px !important;
    }
</style>
```

**Markup**

```
<ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Title="Panel with toolbars" Width="600" Height="300">
    <TopBar>
        <ext:Toolbar runat="server">
            <Items>
                <ext:Button ID="b1" runat="server" Icon="Add" StandOut="true" Text="Notifications">
                    <Listeners>
                        <Render Fn="createTooltp"></Render>
                    </Listeners>
                </ext:Button>
                <ext:ToolbarFill />
                <ext:Button runat="server" EnableToggle="true" ToggleGroup="G1" Icon="GroupAdd" Pressed="true" />
                <ext:Button runat="server" EnableToggle="true" ToggleGroup="G1" Icon="GroupDelete" />
                <ext:Button runat="server" EnableToggle="true" ToggleGroup="G1" Icon="GroupEdit" />
            </Items>
        </ext:Toolbar>
    </TopBar>
</ext:Panel>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function createTooltp(cmp) {
        tooTip = new Ext.ToolTip({
            anchor: 'left',
            target: cmp,
            html: '10',
            cls: 'fbNotification',
            autoRender: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            autoHide: false,
            shadow: false,
            padding: 0,
            width: 16,
            shrinkWrap: 0,
            anchorToTarget: true,
            mouseOffset: [-4, -8]
        });

        tooTip.show();
    }
</script>
```

[image]
The problem now is that the css is not applied properly. Please help!

Comment: Sencha Touch has this [`badge`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button) build-in. They add a `<span>` element on the button. What CSS part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here the version for Ext.NET 1.x. The only thing that you have to do is create own tip anchor sprite image which you can get with any Browser DevTool:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>
    <style>
        .fbNotification
        {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 orange!important;
            border: 1px solid orange !important;
            border-radius: 10px !important;
            width: 18px !important;
        }

        .fbNotification .x-tip-body
        {
            font-size: 10px !important;
        }

        .fbNotification .x-tip-ml {
            background: none;
            padding-left: 3px !important;            
        }

        .fbNotification .x-tip-tc, .fbNotification .x-tip-tl, .fbNotification .x-tip-tr, .fbNotification .x-tip-bc, .fbNotification .x-tip-bl, .fbNotification .x-tip-br, .fbNotification .x-tip-ml, .fbNotification .x-tip-mr 
        {
            background: none;
        }

        .fbNotification .x-tip-anchor 
        {
            /* Put here your own gif image of tip anchor sprite */
            background-image: none; 
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function createTooltp(cmp) {
            var tooTip = new Ext.ToolTip({
                anchor: 'left',
                target: cmp,
                html: '10',
                cls: 'fbNotification',
                autoRender: true,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                autoHide: false,
                shadow: false,
                padding: 0,
                width: 16,
                shrinkWrap: 0,
                anchorToTarget: true,
                mouseOffset: [-4, -8],
                listeners: {
                    beforehide: function () {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            tooTip.show();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Title="Panel with toolbars" Width="600" Height="300">
            <TopBar>
                <ext:Toolbar runat="server">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:Button ID="b1" runat="server" Icon="Add" StandOut="true" Text="Notifications">
                            <Listeners>
                                <Render Fn="createTooltp"></Render>
                            </Listeners>
                        </ext:Button>
                        <ext:ToolbarFill />
                        <ext:Button runat="server" EnableToggle="true" ToggleGroup="G1" Icon="GroupAdd" Pressed="true" />
                        <ext:Button runat="server" EnableToggle="true" ToggleGroup="G1" Icon="GroupDelete" />
                        <ext:Button runat="server" EnableToggle="true" ToggleGroup="G1" Icon="GroupEdit" />
                    </Items>
                </ext:Toolbar>
            </TopBar>
        </ext:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One last thing, the tooltip is hidden on the mouse click. How to always show the tooltip?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

This answer applies to Ext.NET 2.x.

---

Try this one:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
    .fbNotification {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 orange !important;
        border: 1px solid orange !important;
        border-radius: 10px !important;
        width: 18px !important;
    }

    .fbNotification .x-tip-body {
        font-size: 10px !important;
    }
</style>

<script>
    var addNotification = function(cmp) {
        var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            target: cmp,
            html: '10',
            autoRender: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            autoHide: false,
            shadow: false,
            padding: 0,
            cls: 'fbNotification',
            width: 16,
            shrinkWrap: 0
        });
        tip.show();
        tip.alignTo(cmp.el, 'tl-br?', [-14,16]);
    }
</script>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />
        <ext:Panel 
            ID="Panel1" 
            runat="server" 
            Title="Panel with toolbars" 
            Width="600" 
            Height="300">
            <TopBar>
                <ext:Toolbar runat="server">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:Button runat="server" Icon="Add" StandOut="true" Text="Notifications">
                            <Listeners>
                                <Click Handler="Ext.Msg.alert('Click','Click on Add');" />
                                <Render Fn="addNotification"></Render>
                            </Listeners>
                            <ToolTips>
                                <ext:ToolTip runat="server" Html="StandOut button" />
                            </ToolTips>
                        </ext:Button>

                        <ext:ToolbarFill />

                        <ext:Button runat="server" EnableToggle="true" ToggleGroup="G1" Icon="GroupAdd" Pressed="true" />
                        <ext:Button runat="server" EnableToggle="true" ToggleGroup="G1" Icon="GroupDelete" />
                        <ext:Button runat="server" EnableToggle="true" ToggleGroup="G1" Icon="GroupEdit" />
                    </Items>
                </ext:Toolbar>
            </TopBar>
        </ext:Panel>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This example for Ext.NET 2, however it should work with some modifications for Ext.NET 1.x.